# subsetting in xts using a parameter holding dates

Tags: r, subset, xts

I am familiar with the xts subsetting abilities. However, I can't find an elegant way to subset a **parameterized** range of dates. something like this:

```
times = c(as.POSIXct("2012-11-03 09:45:00 IST"),
          as.POSIXct("2012-11-05 09:45:00 IST"))

#create an xts object:
xts.obj = xts(c(1,2),order.by = times)

#filter with these dates:
start.date = as.POSIXct("2012-11-03")
end.date = as.POSIXct("2012-11-04")

#instead of xts["2012-11-03"/"2012-11-04"], do something like this:
xts[start.date:end.date]
```

Does anybody have any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could paste the `start.date` and `end.date` objects together, separating by `"::"` or `"/"`, and then use that to subset.

```
R> xts.obj[paste(start.date,end.date,sep="::")]
                    [,1]
2012-11-03 09:45:00    1
```

Comment: I hesitate to put this but when I read the help I thought it is more efficient to give timeBased index. isn'it?

Comment: @Joshua: thanks a lot! [even though the way you put, it suddenly looks trivial :-)...]

Comment: @agstudy: ISO-style character subsetting _by range_ (i.e. a length 1 vector containing `:` or `/`) is very fast. It is slow is if you subset with an ISO-style character _vector_.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: actually, if your end.date = as.POSIXct("2012-11-05") [instead of the 2012-11-4], then using sep=":" returns only the 1st element. You actually need sep="/". Should I edit your answer?

Comment: @zorbar: whoops, that should have been `::`.

Answer (score 3):

from the help of `[.xts {xts}`

> As xts uses POSIXct time representations of all user-level index
>   classes internally, the fastest timeBased subsetting will always be
>   from POSIXct objects, regardless of the indexClass of the original
>   object.

So you can do subsetting timeBased like this :

```
xts.obj[seq(start.date,end.date,by=60)]
                    [,1]
2012-11-03 09:45:00    1
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. however, start.date and end.date are POSIXct objects. thus, a sequence like you write gave me a sequence with 1-second increments. So, I used it as
    xts.obj[seq(as.Date(start.date),as.Date(end.date),by=1)]
but it gives me an empty list...

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to do the same thing.  Here is my solution, based on the original example.

```
library(xts)

times = c(as.POSIXct("2012-11-03 09:45:00 IST"),
          as.POSIXct("2012-11-05 09:45:00 IST"))

#create an xts object:
xts.obj = xts(c(1,2),order.by = times)

#filter with these dates:
start.date = as.POSIXct("2012-11-03")
end.date = as.POSIXct("2012-11-04")

# By using an index that is the logical AND of two vectors
xts.obj[start.date <= index(xts.obj) & index(xts.obj) <= end.date]
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are racking their brain to do this for non Posix. Especially for quarter based data i.e. 2001 Q2 to 2006 Q3.

I used a simple yet elegant solution:

```
library(xts)

starting.quarter<-"200101"
ending.quarter<-"201702"

oil_price_by_qtr<-oil_price_by_qtr[paste(starting.quarter,ending.quarter,sep="/")]
```

And this will subset the XTS object from 2001 Q1 to 2017 Q2.

May this help some other poor soul avoid losing 2 hours of his life.